# Problems Building ROS Hydro for Debian

Tags: ros, catkin, pythonpath

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The catkin package is giving me all kinds of problems. I have been having problems recently with Import and PYTHONPATH. After adding every catkin_pkg folder I could find to that, this latest block says that --install-layout is not recognized.

```
==> make -j2 -l2 in '/home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin'
    ==> make install in '/home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin'
    Install the project...
    -- Install configuration: "Release"
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/_setup_util.py
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/setup.bash
    -- Installing: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/setup.sh
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/setup.zsh
    -- Installing: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/.rosinstall
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/etc/catkin/profile.d/05.catkin_make.bash
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/etc/catkin/profile.d/05.catkin_make_isolated.bash
    -- Installing: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/pkgconfig/catkin.pc
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig-version.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/package.xml
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/LICENSE
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/eigen/cmake/eigen-config.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/eigen/cmake/eigen-config-version.cmake
    -- Installing: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/string_starts_with.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/list_append_unique.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_python_setup.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/atomic_configure_file.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/assert.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_add_env_hooks.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/python.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/list_append_deduplicate.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/shell.cmake
    -- Installing: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/env-hooks
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/env-hooks/05.catkin_make_isolated.bash
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/env-hooks/05.catkin-test-results.sh.develspace.in
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/env-hooks/05.catkin_make.bash
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/env-hooks/05.catkin-test-results.bat.develspace.in
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/interrogate_setup_dot_py.py
    -- Installing: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/em
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/em/pkg.pc.em
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/em/order_packages.cmake.em
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_generate_environment.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_install_python.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_workspace.cmake
    -- Installing: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/templates
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/templates/Doxyfile.in
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/templates/script.sh.in
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/templates/pkg.context.pc.in
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/templates/generate_cached_setup.py.in
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/templates/relay.py.in
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/templates/setup.sh.in
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/templates/safe_execute_install.cmake.in
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/templates/env.bat.in
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/templates/script.in
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/templates/python_distutils_install.bat.in
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/templates/_setup_util.py.in
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/templates/cfg-extras.context.py.in
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/templates/script.py.in
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/templates/env-hook.context.py.in
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/templates/_setup_util.py
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/templates/setup.bash.in
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/templates/setup.zsh.in
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/templates/env.sh.in
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/templates/script.bash.in
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/templates/order_packages.context.py.in
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/templates/pkgConfig-version.cmake.in
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/templates/__init__.py.in
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/templates/rosinstall.in
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/templates/setup.bat.in
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/templates/python_distutils_install.sh.in
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/templates/pkgConfig.cmake.in
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/em_expand.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_destinations.cmake
    -- Installing: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/platform
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/platform/windows.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/platform/ubuntu.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/platform/lsb.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/parse_arguments.cmake
    -- Installing: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/test
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/test/tests.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/test/gtest.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/test/run_tests.py
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/test/download_checkmd5.py
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/test/catkin_download_test_data.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/test/download_test_data.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/test/nosetests.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/stamp.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/legacy.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/find_program_required.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_metapackage.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/empy.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_libraries.cmake
    -- Installing: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/tools
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/tools/threads.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/tools/rt.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/tools/bz2.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/tools/doxygen.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/tools/libraries.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/order_paths.py
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/list_insert_in_workspace_order.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake
    -- Up-to-date: /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/debug_message.cmake
    + [ -n  ]
    + cd /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin
    + /usr/bin/env PYTHONPATH=/home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/lib/pymodules/:/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/:/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/:/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/catkin_pkg/:/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/catkin_pkg/:~/Modules/:~/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/:~/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/src/:~/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin/:/usr/share/pyshared/:/usr/share/pyshared/catkin_pkg CATKIN_BINARY_DIR=/home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin /usr/local/bin/python /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin/setup.py build --build-base /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin install --install-layout=deb --prefix=/home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated --install-scripts=/home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/bin
    usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: setup.py --help-commands
       or: setup.py cmd --help
    
    error: option --install-layout not recognized
    CMake Error at catkin_generated/safe_execute_install.cmake:4 (message):
      
      execute_process(/home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin/catkin_generated/python_distutils_install.sh)
      returned error code
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      cmake_install.cmake:156 (INCLUDE)
    
    
    make: *** [install] Error 1
    <== Failed to process package 'catkin': 
      Command 'make install' returned non-zero exit status 2
    
    Reproduce this error by running:
    ==> cd /home/cbt33/Modules/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin && make install
    
    Command failed, exiting.
```

Is there an example PYTHONPATH for building ROS that I could get to stop all of the Import/package not found errors? I know that is not the way that catkin is supposed to work but seeing as how it is very temperamental now it would help.

I've also read suggestions about a groovy-gento install with a similar problem but none of those solved it here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193015/problems-building-ros-hydro-for-debian/) by [cbt33](https://answers.ros.org/users/20234/cbt33/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-09-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-09-19**:
Your Debian distro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry I did not follow this up. I completely gave up on Debian and switched Ubuntu.

---

Originally posted by [cbt33](https://answers.ros.org/users/20234/cbt33/) with karma: 16 on 2014-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0